# log centralization and central aggregation system design

Tags: design, logging, distributed-system, projects-and-solutions, multiprocessing

I'm thinking of how would I go about creating my own logging centralization and centralized aggregation system.

Imagined system has 10 - 100 nodes. Each node runs a LAMP(Linux, Apache, MySql, PHP) stack. For the sake of the example only Apache error.log and access.log will be gathered. Then there will be 1 designated node that will be responsible for processing the log files then storing them in a structured data store(MySql Database).

Ingestion phase. On the Web Application nodes there will be a python deamon that will monitor the /var/log/apache2 folder for freshly rotated/zipped logs and then will scp them over to the designated centralized log processing node.

- **Is scp the best way to move the logs to the centralize log processor node?**
- **I will have to store the ssh.pub key on every node.
  Are there any downsides to this other than updating the ssh public
  keys if i need to?**
- **Is gziping and taring all the .gz log files the
  best way to achieve the smallest file size before transmission?**
- **In the resulting
  batch-ji87654edx4dd5678yuhjn8-129344474743.3454333.tar.gz file. I
  will be overloading the filename to infer the node from which the logs
  came from and the timestamp that they were collected. I am split on
  whether I should overload the filename or store an additional config.json file in the tar.gz file for identifier and config info since I cannot think of any other metadata I would be interested in other than node-id and timestamp.**

Not so concerned with real-time data, the delay in accessing recent events is acceptable in this imagined project.

Processing phase. On the centralized log processor node, a python application will be responsible for processing all the zipped logs files and sticking the parsed data into a structured MySql database. The application will use the python multiprocessing module and a thread safe queue to insert the data into the database.

- **When inserting data into the database, do i need to use the thread safe queue or can I just have each individual python processes from the processing pool each have its own database connection and write to the database?**
- **Will the above cause performance problems if i am using InnoDB? It only locks at the row level right.**

Has anyone built a similar system from scratch. Do you see any holes in this design?

I know there are many off the shelf solutions out there but I am doing this as a learning experience for myself.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Dan, welcome to softwareengineering.stackexchange.com. Your question appears very broad. Can you elaborate what trade-offs you are seeing and what specifically you have questions about. See also https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8965/why-questions-about-the-correct-way-are-too-broad

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response Benni. Will add more detail.

Comment: Due to the nature of distributed application deployments, there are a lot of solutions.  If you search for "Application Observability" you will see solutions like Splunk, Elastic Stack, etc.  There are a number of products that can be open source or commercial to solve this very common problem.

Comment: Thanks Berin, however i am doing this as a hobby project and am curious to see what holes are present in my design.